# Change IBus language in current window

Tags: ibus

I'm not sure if this is a bug, or error of expectation or configuration - but when I switch language with IBus (with the m17n engine) it appears not to affect the open window. However, if I open a new one, or close and reopen the existing application, the new language selection takes effect.

My intended use case is to occasionally use a differently scripted language that I'm learning while using Firefox (e.g. to search for a word on Wiktionary), I'd rather not have to use a separate instance of Firefox for it.

I have verified that the same happens with my terminal emulator, it's just with Firefox.

I haven't been able to find documentation describing the behaviour as specifically supporting or not supporting this. Is it supposed to be this way, or can I configure it otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the [IM envionment variables](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IBus#Initial_setup) set in my .xinitrc:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

it did work after a restart. I thought I had logged out and in already, but perhaps not, that should probably be sufficient.